# How could this timestamp method return duplicate values

Tags: c#, unique

I have a method which should generate a unique 10-character timestamp in Base36, with microsecond resolution. However, it is failing uniqueness tests. How can this be?

```
    private static string _lastValue = string.Empty;
    private static readonly DateTime _epoch = DateTime.SpecifyKind(new DateTime(1970,1,1), DateTimeKind.Utc);
    private static readonly DateTime _lastInitialized = DateTime.Now; 
    private static readonly Stopwatch _sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    public static TimeSpan EpochToStopwatchStart()
    {
        return _lastInitialized.Subtract(_epoch);
    }

    public static string GetBase36Timestamp()
    {
        string result;
        do
        {
            // _sw is a running Stopwatch; Microseconds = ticks / 10
            long microseconds = EpochToStopwatchStart().Add(_sw.Elapsed).Ticks / 10L;
            result = MicrosecondsToBase36(microseconds);
        }
        // MicrosecondsToBase36 encodes the Int64 value; the while() loop compares to a
        // tracking field to ensure the encoded value changes from the previous one:
        while (result == _lastValue);
        _lastValue = result;
        return result;
    }
```

I know I discard some resolution, but this requires 10 characters in Base36, and the method checks the encoded value anyway. Unexpected dupes happen during a single run. To simplify the problem I run the tests single-threaded. I expect either the answer will be quite interesting, or I will be quite embarrassed for some very silly oversight in the question.

Comment: Couldn't you just use Ticks directly? I don't know if that would solve the problem though.

Comment: Where are the tests that are failing?

Comment: What makes you think that this can't be called twice in a microsecond? (A microsecond is a reasonably long time... and that's even assuming that the stopwatch *has* microsecond precision.)

Comment: What would be wrong with a simple counter, that you increment with each call? It would not be trivial to make it threadsafe, but your current approach is not threadsafe either.

Comment: @CoderDennis, I truncate to 10 Base36 characters, so I wouldn't capture any of the additional resolution from using ticks directly.

Comment: @cahinton, it fails an integration test that creates timestamps in a tight loop and tries to put them in a hashtable.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I do expect it to be called multiple times in a microsecond, but I expected the `while (result == _lastValue);` loop to mitigate that independently of resolution. I'm sure I'm missing something though.

Comment: @PaulSmith: Right - in a multi-threaded scenario, that code is definitely not safe. But it should be okay with a single thread. Did you say you're still seeing the problem in a single thread? Can you change this into a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: @JonSkeet, your suggestion led me to the real source of the problem: In the process of backporting a base-conversion routine to be .NET 2.0 compatible, I borked the function. It could then return duplicate values, but _non-sequentially_, which is why the while() loop wouldn't catch it. D'oh!

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you add `Thread.Sleep(1);` in your do/while loop?  You are quite possibly getting more than one microsecond generated per iteration.

Comment: Much too slow; I need this to work at a rate of 70k plus per second.

Answer (score 1):

**Analysis**

Creating a multi-threaded performance test reveals that despite the `while` loop, the function is able to exit at a rate of greater than once per microsecond:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> timeStamps = null; ;

        int calls = 1000000;
        int maxThreads = 5;

        for (int threadCount = 1; threadCount <= maxThreads; threadCount++)
        {
            timeStamps = new List<string>(calls * maxThreads);

            var userThread = new ThreadStart(() =>
                {
                    for (int n = 0; n < calls; n++)
                    {
                        timeStamps.Add(TimeStampClass.GetBase36Timestamp());
                    }
                });

            Thread[] threads = new Thread[threadCount];
            var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            for (int j = 0; j < threadCount; j++)
            {
                threads[j] = new Thread(userThread);
                threads[j].Start();
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < threadCount; j++)
            {
                threads[j].Join();
            }

            stopwatch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("threadCount = {0}\n ------------------", threadCount);

            Console.WriteLine("{0} calls in {1} milliseconds", timeStamps.Count, stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ticks per call", (double)stopwatch.Elapsed.Ticks / (double)timeStamps.Count);

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

The resulting output is:

```
threadCount = 1
 ------------------
1000000 calls in 1080 milliseconds
10.802299 ticks per call

threadCount = 2
 ------------------
1985807 calls in 1379 milliseconds
6.94705779564681 ticks per call

threadCount = 3
 ------------------
2893411 calls in 1731 milliseconds
5.98568471606695 ticks per call

threadCount = 4
 ------------------
3715722 calls in 2096 milliseconds
5.64319478152564 ticks per call

threadCount = 5
 ------------------
4611970 calls in 2395 milliseconds
5.19515413153164 ticks per call
```

**Solution for multi-threaded environment:**

Surround your `while` loop with a lock on `_lastValue`:

```
        public static string GetBase36Timestamp()
        {
            string result;
            lock (_lastValue)
            {
                do
                {
                    // _sw is a running Stopwatch; Microseconds = ticks / 10
                    long microseconds = EpochToStopwatchStart().Add(_sw.Elapsed).Ticks / 10L;
                    result = MicrosecondsToBase36(microseconds);
                } while (result == _lastValue);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use [`System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd0811yf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do a thread-safe compare-and-swap as an atomic operation. See [Interlocked Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbhbke0y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for details. In a nutshell, you ...

- Get a copy of the state you want to change as a local variable.
- Perform your computation to get the new state
- Execute `Interlocked.CompareExchange()`, which returns the current *old-value*.
- if your local copy of *old-value* is different than the return value, the swap failed: repeat the above.
- otherwise, you're good to go.

Here's a simplified example, riffing off your work:

```
class TimeStamp
{
  static readonly DateTime  unixEpoch        = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,DateTimeKind.Utc) ;
  static readonly long      BaseMicroseconds = (DateTime.UtcNow-unixEpoch).Ticks / 10L ;
  static readonly Stopwatch Stopwatch        = Stopwatch.StartNew() ;
  static          long      State            = TimeSpan.MinValue.Ticks ;

  private long OffsetInMicroseconds ;

  private TimeStamp()
  {
    long oldState ;
    long newState ;

    do
    {
      oldState = State ;
      newState = Stopwatch.Elapsed.Ticks / 10L ;
    } while (    oldState == newState
              || oldState != Interlocked.CompareExchange( ref State , newState , oldState )
            ) ;

    this.OffsetInMicroseconds = newState ;
    return ;
  }

  public static TimeStamp GetNext()
  {
    return new TimeStamp() ;
  }

  public override string ToString()
  {
    long   v = BaseMicroseconds + this.OffsetInMicroseconds ;
    string s = v.ToString() ; // conversion to Base 36 not implemented ;
    return s ;
  }

}
```